# How to inform the kernel with increased disk space?

Tags: linux, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I was running out of storage space on my wm-ware ubuntu virtual machine and I used Gparted ISO to increased storage space for boot partition. Everything went well until I got a msg saying that Gparted unable to inform kernel of changes.

Is there a command that would make kernel run like an update check? Im am using Ubuntu 14.04 TLS.

Comment: Yes, the command is called "reboot".

Comment: reboot did not make it. I still get the low storage msg.